# Can Dolphin create copies of a file in the same folder without prompting for a new name?

Tags: kde, dolphin

As a former Microsoft Windows user, I'm used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on a file, which then creates a copy/copies of the same file.

Attempting this in Dolphin results in a prompt that the file already exists and that I should enter a different target file name. Can Dolphin be configured to match Microsoft's Windows behaviour?

Microsoft Windows creates `example.txt - Copy`, `example.txt - Copy (2)`, `example.txt - Copy (3)` and so on without asking for an alternative filename.

Comment: What do you want should happen? Say you have `example.txt`. What should the copied file be named? Assume readers here aren't familiar with what Microsoft Windows does.

Comment: AFAICT, there doesn't seem to be any option for altering Dolphin's behavior in the way you describe. However, if you're using a Linux distro with the KDE Plasma desktop environment you can do part of what you want by using Service Menus. When set up, you can right-click on a file and make a copy which will have, for example, a time-stamp appended to the end of the filename to distinguish it from the original.

Comment: @DKBose: That's pretty much the answer I was looking for. I would accept this as an answer if there'd be the checkmark along your comment, so I was only able to upvote it.

Comment: Hi, I didn't post an answer initially because I was unsure whether a workaround would be acceptable. I've now posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit added on 20200322 relevant to a future version of Dolphin:

> Dolphin has a new “Duplicate” feature that can be used to quickly create copies of selected items (me: Nate Graham, Dolphin 20.04.0)

[Source](https://pointieststick.com/2020/03/21/this-week-in-kde-new-features-start-rolling-in/)

---

I too feel the need to sometimes copy/paste the same file in its current location. Obviously, the filename has to be modified somewhat. Dolphin does not automatically provide names such as `example.txt - Copy`, `example.txt - Copy (2)`, `example.txt - Copy (3)` to distinguish copies from the original but provides an interface allowing the user to modify the filename of each copy made.

I prefer the simpler route of adding timestamps with the help of *Dolphin Service Menus* as described below.

Consider a file titled `out.mp4`. The image below shows the original and a few copies with time stamps.

[image: Dolphin showing timestamped copies]

### Making timestamped copies using Service Menus in Dolphin.

Service Menus allow users to customize the context menu of Dolphin to provide additional features.

Create `/home/dkb/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus` (where `dkb` is to be changed appropriately).

In there, create an empty text file named `copy-with-stamp.desktop`

Paste in the following content:

```
[Desktop Action copy-with-stamp]
Exec=cp-with-timestamp.sh %U
Name=Add timestamp as suffix
Icon=edit-copy

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=copy-with-stamp
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/all
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
```

and save the file as plain text.

Notice `Exec=cp-with-timestamp.sh %U` in which `cp-with-timestamp.sh` is an *executable* with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp "$@" "$@"-"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
```

You can make the timestamp more or less elaborate depending on your needs. `man date` explains how. But you must ensure that `cp-with-timestamp.sh` is *executable* (which can be done in Dolphin itself) and stored in your `$PATH` (or provide the entire path and filename in the `Exec=line`). I have `~/bin` in my `$PATH` and so I keep `cp-with-timestamp.sh` in `~/bin`.

Once you've created both the .desktop file and the executable script, you can right-click on any file in your home folder and see the context menu option:

[image: Dolphin's modified context menu]:

Note that my context menu isn't standard: I've removed some things, added others.

---

### More reading

- There's a long thread on Service Menus at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin/)
- People develop and contribute Service Menus over at the [KDE Store](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/102/). One caution is to make sure you're considering Service Menus relevant to your KDE Plasma version.
- For people coming from other operating systems, [safe names for files and folders](https://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201607/page03.html) maybe worth a read so that the implications of using spaces, `'`, `(`, `)`, etc are well understood.